# Can SQLiteOpenHelper load table scripts from external files?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is it possible to load table creation scripts from flat files when creating the SQLite database in Android?

I am going to have multiple tables and all the examples I have seen online using the SQLite helper classes, include the script text in the Java file and I'd rather not clutter up my class.

Comment: You can also use a pre-populated database, keep it in assests folder like explained here,http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The same as with copying file from assets (https://gist.github.com/1271795) you can read file and execute commands on newly created SQLiteDatabase.